# How can I use two buttons in one custom tableView cell ? I want to when clicked in one button change the icons of both of them

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is method for actions of buttons

```
 @objc func recived()
    {
        kind = false
        self.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewWillAppear(true)

    }
    @objc func paid()
    {
        kind = true
        self.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewWillAppear(true)
    }
```

Here tableView indexPath method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "kindCell", for: indexPath) as! KindTableViewCell

    if kind == true {
        cell.recivedButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector (recived), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green on"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.paidButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "red off"), for: UIControlState.normal)   
    }
    else{
        cell.paidButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector (paid), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.paidButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "red on"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green off"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: You should *never* call `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` yourself

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this logic in the cell itself. Hook your outlets and actions up in Interface Builder, and then…

```
class KindTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var receivedButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var paidButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func received(_ sender: UIButton) {
        recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green on"), for: .normal)
        paidButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "red off"), for: .normal)           
    }

    @IBAction func paid(_ sender: UIButton) {
        paidButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "red on"), for: .normal)
        recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green off"), for: .normal)    
    }
}
```

Notice how the button outlets are `private` - this removes the temptation to update them in the view controller. Let the cell update its own state.

If you need to do additional work in your view controller, add a delegate protocol to your table view cell…

```
protocol KindTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func kindTableViewCellDidTapReceive(_ kindTableViewCell: KindTableViewCell)
    func kindTableViewCellDidTapPaid(_ kindTableViewCell: KindTableViewCell)
}

class KindTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Outlets

    var delegate: KindTableViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func received(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Update button state
        delegate?.kindTableViewCellDidTapReceive(self) 
    }

    @IBAction func paid(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Update button state
        delegate?.kindTableViewCellDidTapPaid(self) 
    }
}
```

Then in your table view controller…

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "kindCell", for: indexPath) as! KindTableViewCell

     cell.delegate = self
     return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple images on button according to states:

> 1: For normal state

```
    cell.recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green off"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

> 1: For selected state

```
    cell.recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green on"), for: UIControlState.selected)
```

Now, You can handle button states, button auto select the images according to button states, You have to add this to custom class like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        cell.recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green off"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.recivedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "green on"), for: UIControlState.selected)
        cell.paidButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "red off"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.paidButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "red on"), for: UIControlState.selected)

    }
```

Now , You need to handle button selected states like this in button target methods:

```
sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
```

Or can check condition that `paidButton` is clicked then paid button `isSlected` is true and `recivedButton` `isSelected` is false 
Example:

```
@objc func recived(_ sender: UIButton)
    { 
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected 
    paidButton.isSelected = sender.isSelected

    }

@objc func paid(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected 
    recivedButton.isSelected = sender.isSelected
    }
```